# Solving Geometric Transformations

Tags: geometry, systems-of-equations

I am trying to understand my notes on geometric image transformations.

-"A pixel at coordinate (x,y) in the original image moves to the location ((2x+y)/3, x) in the new image.

The pixel is now at (y, 3x-2y)."

I'm really confused how (2x+y)/3 becomes 3x-2y.
Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Please let me know if I've left out any important information that would be helpful in solving this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set
\begin{align}
y' = \frac{2x+y}{3} \ \ \text{ and } \ \ x' = x
\end{align}
then you will see that
\begin{align}
3y'=2x'+y \ \Rightarrow \ \ y = 3y'-2x'.
\end{align}